# SQL Join on tables with from to entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I want to join. However the information is written as from to in the first table.

My first table looks like this:

```
No. | Date       | From entry | To Entry |
+---+------------+------------+----------+
1   | 21.12.2013 | 3          | 10
```

My second table looks like this:

```
| Entry  |  Code |
+--------+-------+
| 3      | 1     |
| 4      | 0     |
| 5      | 2     |
| 6      | 3     |
| 7      | 1     |
| 8      | 0     |
| 9      | 6     |
| 10     | 1     |
```

I want to join both based on the from to information. The result should look like this:

```
| Entry  | Code  | Date       |
+--------+-------+------------+
| 3      | 1     | 21.12.2013 |
| 4      | 0     | 21.12.2013 |
| 5      | 2     | 21.12.2013 |
| 6      | 3     | 21.12.2013 |
| 7      | 1     | 21.12.2013 |
| 8      | 0     | 21.12.2013 |
| 9      | 6     | 21.12.2013 |
| 10     | 1     | 21.12.2013 |
```

I have no idea how to achieve this with t-sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify correct condition for the `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT          *
FROM            table1
INNER JOIN      table2 ON  table2.Entry >= table1.[From entry] 
                       AND table2.Entry <= table1.[To entry]
```

Or you may consider using `LEFT JOIN` if you want to return all records from table1 no matter if they have related records in table2.

Comment: @Peter Jackson glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (`INNER JOIN` and `BETWEEN AND`)

```
SELECT 
       Entry, Code, Date
FROM   
       Table1 T1 INNER JOIN
       Table2 T2
              ON T2.Entry BETWEEN T1.[From entry] AND T1.[To entry]
```

Comment: Please don't use the Old-style join syntax: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Select table2.*,
table1.date
from table2
left join table1 on 
table2.entry between table1.fromentry and table1.toentry
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f14f51/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT  B.Entry,B.Code,A.Date
FROM    Table1 A CROSSJOIN Table2 B
WHERE   B.Entry >= A.[From Entry] AND B.Entry <= A.[To Entry]
```

Comment: Why would you use `CROSSJOIN` ?

Comment: Just because I brought the CONDITION to WHERE part. I believe, the better way is yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks I just saw interesting post about the `CROSS JOIN` which indicates that he underlying behavior would be the same as for the  `INNER JOIN` when the WHERE clause is used for conditions. Was not aware about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Entry, Code, (SELECT T1.Date 
                    FROM FirstTable T1 
                    WHERE T1.Entry BETWEEN T2.[From Entry] 
                        AND T2.[To Entry]) AS Date
FROM SecondTable T2
```